# Overlay two sound tracks with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, web

I have two soundtracks(two .mp3 files) and I am looking for a way to "overlap" these tracks on one another, that is overlay one over the other. Is there any way to do this in Node.js?

Comment: Please clarify: When you say "soundtrack", what do you mean exactly? Do you have two sound files that you want to mix together and write the result to a third file? If yes, what format are these files in? (wav/mp3/ogg)?

Answer (score 1):

SOX provide utility to do audio manipulations
it do have its implementation in nodejs https://github.com/andrewrk/node-sox

**or**

You can refers to this post 
http://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2013/5/31/using-nodejs-to-join-audio-files

**Note : nodejs do provide ffmpeg implmentations you can find something in that**
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg